# Opening Excel file and Saving as CSV in R

Tags: r

I'm using the following code:

```
setwd("~/R/Test")
require(openxlsx)
file_list <- list.files(getwd())

for (file in file_list){
  file = read.xlsx(file)
  write.csv(file,file=file)
}
```

Where it opens each file in a directory, reads the excel file, and saves as a CSV. However, I'm trying to source the original file name, and save the CSV with the original file name. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're overwriting the variable `file`, which used to contain the original file name, in the line `file = read.xlsx(file)`. Just avoid doing that.

Comment: Please describe  what you want is different than what you are getting. That code appears to be doing what you say you want.

Comment: @Frank - so if I just remove the 'file=' portion, would it pull the original name and then save with that same? Because if I just remove that portion I'm not seeing what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you're overwriting the variable `file`. I also recommend changing the extension of the file. Try this as your for loop:

```
for (file in file_list) {
  file.xl <- read.xlsx(file)
  write.csv(file.xl, file = sub("xlsx$", "csv", file))
}
```

Note that you'll need to change the `"xlsx$"` to `"xls$"` depending on what the extensions are of the files in your directory.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Can you help me understand the file.xl portion? is that just generating a new variable?

Comment: @GregdeLima Yes, it's making a new variable. `file` will stay as the string that contains the spreadsheet's name, and `file.xl` will be the data frame that actually contains all of the info.

Comment: Thank you! I hate when the answer is so simple and it just goes over my head.

Comment: @GregdeLima I also recommend looking into setting `quote = F` and `row.names = F` inside the `write` function, but you should check out the csv files to make sure you want that.

Comment: - Can you elaborate on those? Looked into the help for each, but I'm not following.

Comment: @GregdeLima `quote = F` removes the double quotes from strings in the csv file, and `row.names = F` removes row names from each line of the csv. You may want row names, but I usually remove them when they are just row numbers. You may also want quotes around strings, I just wanted to make you aware of the ability to disable them.